# Pie Cutting Puzzle

Tags: puzzle

Here's a tasty puzzle.

Alice would like to share a slice of pie with Bob. Alice doesn't like crust so she decides to cut the pie cross-wise. However, she wants to make sure that she's giving herself and Bob an even amount.

Given the scenario below, how far up the pie edge (r/R) should Alice make her cut?

[image]

a = Alice's slice area, b = Bob's slice area

Comment: What's the angle of the slice?

Comment: How thick is the crust in relation to the radius of the pie?  That is, is it possible that the crust is a significant portion of the pie?

Comment: @Peter - Let's assume it is a pie cut into eighths.

Answer (score 1):

If the angle of the slice is $\theta$, then $a = \dfrac{1}{2}r^2 \sin\theta$ and $b = \dfrac{1}{2}R^2 \theta -a$. For them to be equal $$r = \sqrt{\frac{\theta}{2 \sin\theta}}\; R$$ 
Note that eight slices means $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Just a note that might seem obvious: this result is valid only if the slice angle is less than about 108 degrees ($r\le R$). For larger angles you don't have a solution